# Add column with conditional values located anywhere in certain other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have seen many questions about adding conditional columns to a dataframe, which typically rely on using `np.where()`. As far as I can tell, `np.where()` only looks in the same row it's appending to. For example:

```
# Create df with 3 columns of random numbers from 0 to 100
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

---------------
A    B    C
23   16   85
 9   74   12
99   24   83
---------------
# Add new column based on values in other columns
conditions = [
    (df['A'] == 9),
    (df['B'] == 16)),
    (df['A'] == 99) & (df['C'] == 83)]
choices = ['Good', ' Better', 'Best']
df['How_Good'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Awful')

---------------
A    B    C    How_Good
23   16   85    Better
 9   74   12     Good
99   24   83     Best
---------------
```

In this case, the new column's values directly corresponded to the values in other columns in the same row.

However, I want to produce a column that has values which are conditional based on any value in a particular column. For example, imagine I have a df such that:

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'Name': ['Al', 'Mo', 'Q'], 
        'Owned': ['Car', 'Truck', 'Bike'],
        'ID_1': [5, 7, 1], 'Name_1':['Jo', 'Ry', 'We']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

------------
ID   Name    Owned    ID_1    Name_1
1     Al      Car       5       Jo
2     Mo     Truck      7       Ry
3     Q      Bike       1       We
------------
```

Now I want to add another column `Match` which displays the value of `Owned` when `ID_1 == ID`, but not necessarily in the same row. Basically, it would have to check `ID` against every value in `ID_1` and stop once it finds a match. Therefore the df with the appended column would look like:

```
------------
     ID   Name    Owned    ID_1    Name_1    Match
0    1     Al      Car       5       Jo       nan
1    2     Mo     Truck      7       Ry       nan
2    3     Q      Bike       1       We       Car
------------
```

In the above example, `ID` in row 0 matched with `ID_1` in row 2 (there were no other matches). Then it took the value of `Owned` from row 0 and put it into `Match`. Therefore the new column `Match` is looking for a matches between `ID` and `ID_1` throughout the dataframe. When this is true, it puts in the value from `Owned` into `Match`, otherwise `nan`.

The caveats are that there are only a set amount of things under `Owned`: it can only be either Car, Truck, or Bike. But both `ID` and `ID_1` can repeat many times. There are also many more columns for `ID_2`, `ID_3` and so on, all of which match on `ID` and use the value in `Owned`.

Comment: probably a case for `map` `d_ = dict(zip(df.ID,df.Owned))` `df['Match'] = df['ID_1'].map(d_)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.apply` as below:

```
df['Match'] = df.apply(lambda row: df[df['ID'] == row['ID_1']].loc[:, 'Owned'], axis=1)
```

If you have a more complicated criteria, you might want to put them in a function and then apply it.

Comment: When I do this, I get `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1` with a `KeyError: 'Match'`. Do you know why this is?

Comment: I just ran `d = ...` and `df = ...` from your question above followed by my answer and obtained the Series [NaN, NaN, 'Car']. Not sure why you are getting an error.

Comment: @Quang Hoang's solution below is significantly faster that mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `merge`:

```
df.merge(df[['Name','ID']].rename(columns={'Name':'Match',
                                           'ID':'ID_1'}), 
         on='ID_1',
         suffixes=['','_re'],
         how='left')
```

Output:

```
   ID Name  Owned  ID_1 Name_1 Match
0   1   Al    Car     5     Jo   NaN
1   2   Mo  Truck     7     Ry   NaN
2   3    Q   Bike     1     We    Al
```

Answer (score 1):

With your full data, you could use a loop to expand on this:

```
df.loc[2,'Match'] = df.loc[df.loc[2].ID_1-1].Owned

#Out[2615]: 
#   ID Name  Owned  ID_1 Name_1 Match
#0   1   Al    Car     5     Jo   NaN
#1   2   Mo  Truck     7     Ry   NaN
#2   3    Q   Bike     1     We   Car
```